# NSubstitute Checking received calls don't work

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

Hey guys im new with the NSubstitute framework. I'm trying to test some of my classes, but when i use NSubstitute to check received calls it says received no matching calls.

I'm trying to test if the method Tick() is receiving LogEvent() and HandleEvent(...) from event class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ATM_System.Event;
using ATM_System.EventDetection;
using ATM_System.Region;
using ATM_System.Track;

namespace ATM_System
{
public class ATM
{
    private List<ITrack> _tracks;//this list contains both Tracks and airpotrs
    private IRegion _region;
    private List<IEventDetection> _eventdetects;
    private List<IEvent> _events;



    public ATM(List<ITrack> airports, int region_size, List<IEventDetection> elist)
    //Sets airports, regionsize, and eventdetectors
    {
        _tracks = airports;
        _region = new Region.Region(region_size,region_size); 
        _events = new List<IEvent>();
        _eventdetects = elist;

    }

    public void Tick() //The tick function which is called each 250 ms
    {

        // update track positions
        foreach (var track1 in _tracks)
        {
            track1.update();
        }

        //check for events
        foreach (var detector in _eventdetects)
        {
            _events.AddRange(detector.DetectEvent(_tracks)); //this is simple: add the event list that the "detectevent" will 
                                                             //will return to the _events list
        }

        //handle events and output
        foreach (var event1 in _events)
        {
            event1.HandleEvent(_tracks);

            event1.LogEvent();
        }

    }

    public void Addairport(Airport AP)
    {
        _tracks.Add(AP);

    }

    public void IncomingTrack(ITrack track) //is called from main function when a new track is entering the region
    {
        //add incoming track
        _tracks.Add(track);
    }
}
}
```

TEST FILE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ATM_System.Event;
using ATM_System.EventDetection;
using ATM_System.Track;
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace ATM_System.Tests.Unit
{
[TestFixture]
class ATMUnitTests
{
    private ATM _uut;
    private ITrack _track;
    private IEvent _event;
    private IEventDetection _eventDetection;

    private int _rsize;
    private List<ITrack> _tracks;
    private List<IEventDetection> _eDetections;


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _track = Substitute.For<ITrack>();
        _event = Substitute.For<IEvent>();
        _eventDetection = Substitute.For<IEventDetection>();

        _tracks = new List<ITrack>();
        _eDetections = new List<IEventDetection>();

        _uut = new ATM(_tracks, _rsize, _eDetections);

    }


    [Test]
    public void Tick_UpdateTrack_TrackUpdated()
    {
        _uut.IncomingTrack(_track);
        _uut.Tick();
        _track.Received().update();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Tick_LogEvent_EventLogged()
    {
        //HOW?
    }

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSubstitute Checking received calls don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346720/nsubstitute-checking-received-calls-dont-work)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to verify that your `Tick` method calls `HandleEvent` and `LogEvent` on `IEvent` objects.

In order to do this, you will need to mock `IEvent` and somehow pass that mock to your `Tick` method.

One possible way to do this (in your current design) is to have your `_eventDetection` mock return said `IEvent` mock in its `DetectEvent` method. You keep a reference to this mock and verify that `HandleEvent` and `LogEvent` are called on it.